# Symbolic link: From NTFS partition to ext4 partition?

Tags: symbolic-link

hope you all fine. Can i make a symbolic link of a file from **NTFS partition** to **ext4 partition**? For example, i wanna make a link from `/media/username/mydeviceName/DIRECTORYNAME` (which is NTFS partition)  to `~/Desktop` (ext4 partition).

Comment: Why do you ask the same question again?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create a symbolic link from NTFS partition to a ext4 partition and vice versa.

It's just a file referencing to an other address.

And also:

> NTFS 3.1 introduced support for symbolic links for any type of file ... in migration and application compatibility with POSIX operating systems. Microsoft aimed for Windows Vista's symbolic links to "function just like UNIX links".
>
> Additionally, NTFS symbolic links to files are distinct from NTFS symbolic links to directories and therefore cannot be used interchangeably, unlike on POSIX where the same symbolic link can refer to either files or directories.
>
> [[symbolic link]](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)